# Can a JavaScript modal dialog be modal only to the tab and not to the whole browser window?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

Modern browsers have multi-tab interface, but JavaScript function `window.showModalDialog()` creates a modal dialog that blocks *all* of the tabs.

I'd like to know if there is a way to create a modal dialog that blocks only the tab it's been created in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use one of the more 'Ajax-like' modal dialogs, which are just absolute positioned divs, floating on top of everything else.

Those are modal to the 'document' and not the browser.

For instance take a look it [this jQuery plugin](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)

P.S. `showModalDialog()` is an IE only call, so you might want to not use that altogether.

Comment: Mmm, funny, all sites report that it isn't supported. Do you have a life example?

Comment: actually Firefox (3 at least) does implement the showModalDialog() method. Not sure since when... but agreed the abs. pos. div is a better choice.

Comment: @Michiel: try this in FF3
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<a href="javascript:d();">Show</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function d()
{
var f = "dialogLeft:100;dialogTop:100;dialogWidth:500;dialogHeight:400;";
 showModalDialog("http://google.com",window,f);
}
</script>
</body>
&

Answer (score 2):

Nope. It's conceivable IE8's ‘loose coupling’ might behave like this at some point, but it doesn't in the current betas.

I second Michiel's recommendation. A pseudo-modal-dialogue working by obscuring the rest of the page, floating a div on top, and calling the script back when it's finished, is both:

- much more usable/less annoying than a real modal dialog
- compatible with any browser

showModalDialog/showModelessDialog themselves are generally to be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

[Firefox 3 supports window.showModalDialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.showModalDialog) (but it also blocks all tabs).